# Wait for onClickListener

Tags: java, android, loops, onclicklistener

I'm trying to solve this Problem, but I don't make any progress,

This is my Code example:

```
while (x<5){

       button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            //Do something
    }
 });
x++;
}
```

In this case he goes through the while-loop 5 times in a fraction of a second.

But I want him to go in the while-loop and wait for clicking button2. When button2 is pressed, I want him to do the onClick(), go out of it and then start at the beginning of the Loop again.

And not 5 times at once.

I hope you understand my problem. I'm grateful for every Support.

Comment: a while loop is the wrong construct for this. Add a field `counter` inside your `OnClickListener`, increment it in `onClick` and do *something* if it goes over 4 or 5

Comment: why are you using loop then ?? if you just use the onClick listener...it will work..according to your need

Comment: Thank you for this tip. I've already thought about that but in my case I'm developing a very complex "game" in which I have to put certain Teams in order. But if this is really the only single way, I have to do that.

Comment: All this code is doing is creating new instances of on click listeners for that button while that loop is going which makes no sense

Comment: @tyczj I Need the Loop because the users can choose the number of rounds which they want to Play.

Comment: Yeah so again your looping is wasting memory because you are creating new listeners each time. All you have to do is increment x when onClick is called

Comment: @tyczj Okay, I will try it out. Thank u for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you may want to increase your x value in the click event instead of while loop.

You may try this:

```
int x = 0;
button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            x++;
        }
}
while(x < 5){
//do your thing
}
```

The question is very unclear. However this might help you if I get it right.

A little note: Using a loop and a listener in that way may not be a good practice. You may want to try a different approach to your problem.

As always,
Have a nice day.